# Python Regex Help

Tags: python, html, regex

I am trying to sort through HTML tags and I can't seem to get it right.

What I have done so far

```
import urllib
import re

s = raw_input('Enter URL: ')
f = urllib.urlopen(s) 
s = f.read() 
f.close 
r = re.compile('<TAG\b[^>]*>(.*?)</TAG>',)
result = re.findall(r, s)
print(result)
```

Where I replace "TAG" with tag I want to see.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use an XML parser to parse HTML.  Mandatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regex. Regex is an insufficiently complex tool to parse HTML. If someone is asking you to do this, beat them over the head with a stick and then use BeautifulSoup instead. It'll be less painful for the both of you.

Comment: What sort of results are you currently getting?

Comment: It is not a good idea to use a xml parser if you are scanning html from the web some html page are very far from a xml compliant file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example from BS is this

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
doc = ['<html><head><title>Page title</title></head>',
       '<body><p id="firstpara" align="center">This is paragraph <b>one</b>.',
       '<p id="secondpara" align="blah">This is paragraph <b>two</b>.',
       '</html>']
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(doc))
soup.findAll('b')
[<b>one</b>, <b>two</b>]
```

As for a regular expression, you can use

```
aa = doc[0]
aa
'<html><head><title>Page title</title></head>'
pt = re.compile('(?<=<title>).*?(?=</title>)')
re.findall(pt,aa)
['Page title']
```

Answer (score 5):

You should really try using libraries which can perform HTML parsing out of the box. Beautiful Soup is one of my favorites.

Comment: BeautifulSoup is _perfect_ for this.

Comment: This is a regex learning experience and it was the only real example I could come up with.

I.E. if dog.avicat.avipig.jpg is there anyway I could sort it out to be 
dog.avi
cat.avi
pig.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear on what you are trying to achieve with the regex. Capturing the contents between two div tags for instance works with

```
re.compile("<div.*?>.*?</div>")
```

Although you will run into some problems with nested divs with the above one.

Comment: I think you forgot the parentheses around the capture group. Did you mean: re.compile("<div.*?>(.*?)</div>")?

Comment: He's not using the capture group in his code for anything so I thought it wasn't needed. I'm sure an able programmer can add it should the need for one arise.